# Samsung phone - What does "OLM" mean for the CSC Code?

Tags: samsung, radio-firmware

I attempted to root my (new) Samsung A24 - and while that worked, I've been having issues with the phone suddenly being unable to make or receive calls after a random number of hours until I reboot it.  I'm trying to work through this.

While I did flash the phone with firmware that claims to be for my region (NZ - so XNZ), the CSC files don't mention "XNZ" in them, they mention "OLM".

I've been unable to find out what this means.  I did discover OXM is some kind of universal software, so I'm wondering what OLM stands for, and also wondering if it is appropriate for my region!

Comment: I haven't dug deeper but looks like OXM and OLM are multi-CSC codes: [Changing multi CSC from OLM to OXM using combination ROM?](https://xdaforums.com/t/changing-multi-csc-from-olm-to-oxm-using-combination-rom.4237955/)